# How does the performance of dictionary key lookups compare in Python?

Tags: python, performance

How does:

```
dict = {}
if key not in dict:
 dict[key] = foo
```

Compare to:

```
try:
 dict[key]
except KeyError:
 dict[key] = foo
```

ie, is the look up of a key in anyway faster than the linear search through `dict.keys()`, that I assume the first form will do?

Comment: There's also the dict.setdefault method: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: The first does **not** do a linear seach. As Larry Wall put it: "Doing linear scans over an associative array is like trying to club someone to death with a loaded Uzi." `dict.__contains__` does roughly the same as the first 2/3 of `dict.__getitem__` (a hash lookup).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on how often the key is already in the dict (BTW, has anyone mentioned to you how bad an idea it is to hide a builtin such as `dict` behind a variable?)

```
if key not in dct:
 dct[key] = foo
```

If the key is in the dictionary this does one dictionary lookup. If the key is in the dictionary it looks up the dictionary twice.

```
try:
 dct[key]
except KeyError:
 dct[key] = foo
```

This may be slightly faster for the case where the key is in the dictionary, but throwing an exception has quite a big overhead, so it is almost always not the best option.

```
dct.setdefault(key, foo)
```

This one is slightly tricky: it always involves two dictionary lookups: the first one is to find the `setdefault` method in the `dict` class, the second is to look for `key` in the `dct` object. Also if `foo` is an expression it will be evaluated every time whereas the earlier options only evaluate it when they have to.

Also look at `collections.defaultdict`. That is the most appropriate solution for a large class of situations like this.

Comment: Good point on using 'dict' I changed the variable name when typing the example and didn't think about it. The key key is usually not in the dict.

Comment: I'll be going with collections.defaultdict, thanks for pointing that out. It seems pythonic, and a hair faster than dict.setdefault()

Comment: Its very common to see dict = {} , str =  "something" ... overriding the builtin keyword . some languages dont allow that .

Answer (score 8):

Just to clarify one point: `if key not in d` doesn't do a linear search through d's keys.  It uses the dict's hash table to quickly find the key.

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to find out - ta!

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the setdefault method:

```
>>> r = {}
>>> r.setdefault('a', 'b')
'b'
>>> r
{'a': 'b'}
>>> r.setdefault('a', 'e')
'b'
>>> r
{'a': 'b'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try: `my_dict.setdefault(key, default)`. It's slightly slower than the other options, though.

> If `key` is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert `key` with a value of `default` and return `default`. `default` defaults to None.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

example_dict = dict(zip(range(10), range(10)))

def kn(key, d):
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = 'foo'

def te(key, d):
    try:
        d[key]
    except KeyError:
        d[key] = 'foo'

def sd(key, d):
    d.setdefault(key, 'foo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer

    t = Timer("kn(2, example_dict)", "from __main__ import kn, example_dict")
    print t.timeit()
    t = Timer("te(2, example_dict)", "from __main__ import te, example_dict")
    print t.timeit()
    t = Timer("sd(2, example_dict)", "from __main__ import sd, example_dict")
    print t.timeit()

    # kn: 0.249855041504
    # te: 0.244259119034
    # sd: 0.375113964081
```

Comment: It's quite interesting that the python built in method is so much slower.

Comment: Function call overhead, I suppose.

Comment: And it's interesting that with `psyco.full()`, all three variants only take about 10% of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the timing data! I also tested collections.defaultdict and found it to perform better than setdefault, but worse than kn and te.

Answer (score -1):

`my_dict.get(key, foo)` returns foo if key isn't in my_dict. The default value is None, so `my_dict.get(key)` will return None if key isn't in my_dict. The first of your options is better if you want to just add key to your dictionary. Don't worry about speed here. If you find that populating your dictionary is a hot spot in your program, then think about it. But it isn't. So don't.

Comment: That doesn't set the value if it's not set by looking at his code it appears he's checking if the key exists and setting it otherwise.

Comment: @GWW: True. You could use `dict[key] = dict.get(key, foo)` though.

Comment: I suppose so, but then why not just use dict.setdefault(key,value)

Comment: that's entirely incorrect. Did you ever try doing a thing called "reading the documentation"?